# get 302 redirect url using php

Tags: php, redirect

I was able to use [How To Get Redirect URL In PHP](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/07/05/how-to-get-redirect-url-in-php/comment-page-1/#comments)

but now it does not work anymore. site where I try to get redirect url is using temporary 302 redirection.
It gives me "05 Request method 'HEAD' not supported"

Only way for me to see "link" if I put get_headers in my script, I will get bunch of stuff and I see redirect displayed in "[Cache-Control] => private [Location] => http://www.test.com" towards end.

How do I modify above script to work with this new 302 redirect?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server doesn't support `HEAD`, you could retry with `GET`. Make sure that if you do this you only search for the `Location` header in the headers (not in the body).